# Why doesn't Python 3 itertools.chain let me implement multiranges

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-itertools

I'm trying to implement the idea of a *multirange*, sort of the equivalent of concatenated multiple ranges, using `itertools.chain` as follows:

```
a = np.array( range( 37 ) )
print("a", a, file = sys.stderr)
c = chain(range(0,13), range(23,29 ) )
print( "list(c)", list(c), file = sys.stderr )
```

So far, so good.  Next, I want to use `c` as a compound array index, similar to how I could say

```
a[ range(2,8) ]  =>  array( [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ] )
```

So, here goes:

```
x = a[ c ]
print( "x", x, file = sys.stderr )
```

But...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-192fff14b87d> in <module>
      3 c = chain(range(0,13), range(23,29 ) )
      4 print( "list(c)", list(c), file = sys.stderr )
----> 5 x = a[c]
      6 print( "x", x, file = sys.stderr )

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Clearly, this is another of the Python indexing mysteries.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and help me figure out how to get my intent ("multirange").  I understand that I could probably just use `list(c)` for indexing, but I think that undoes the other part of my intent, namely, enumerate the implied set of indices lazily.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, only valid indices are `integers`, `slices` and `ellipsis`
and here `c` is a instance of `<class 'itertools.chain'>`

What you can do instead is convert that to list and then use it.

```
>>> c = chain(range(0,13), range(23,29 ) )
>>> a[list(c)]
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 23, 24, 25, 26,
       27, 28])
```